# Google sheet formula conditions

Tags: google-sheets-formula

The google sheet Expenses tab allows the user to define the start and end month for the item cost. The Timeline tab displays the item cost starting on the assigned month number.
What needs to change with the formula to also set the end month number on the timeline and display the monthly cost in the month range?

Formula:

```
=if(Expenses!$E2<=C$2,(Expenses!$D2/12),0)
```

[Google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yTvtz7NUf1yU69xfXib2kx2OINIDU_tCVSQ1dMib8J4/edit?usp=sharing)

This formula almost does what I need. Except that it fails when the being month number is 1.

```
=if( and( Expenses!$E2 <= E$4, E$4 <= Expenses!$F2), Expenses!$D2 / ((Expenses!$F2)-(Expenses!$E2)+1), iferror(1/0) )
```

How can include another if statement in the formula
so that:

if the beginning month is 1 do not add 1 to the divisor

```
((Expenses!$F2)-(Expenses!$E2))
```

Else add 1 to the divisor

```
((Expenses!$F2)-(Expenses!$E2)+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=IF(AND(Expenses!$E2 <= D$4, D$4 <= Expenses!$F2), 
 Expenses!$D2 / ((Expenses!$F2)-(Expenses!$E2)+IF(D$4=1, 1, 0)), IFERROR(1/0))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help, I made it work and have one follow-up question.
Is there a way to add a - or 0 to the empty cells that have the formula?
When the formula populates a cell with a value the dash is replaced with the value. [image]

Comment: Please do not ask questions in answers. Extra questions should be asked in new questions, or, if they're minor enough, be asked in a comment underneath this question on of its answers.